# Workless Gem v-1.2.3 not scaling down worker in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am using

Rails 4.2
Workless 1.2.3

Workless is working fine in scaling up worker, but it is not scaling down the worker after completing the job.

Things I have done:

(1) Removed "worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work" from Profile

(2) Added code to config/init/workless.rb

```
Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job.class_eval do
  after_destroy "self.class.scaler.down"
  after_create "self.class.scaler.up"
  after_update "self.class.scaler.down"
end
```

Not sure what I am missing. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with some bad data. Ran

```
Delayed::Job.destroy_all
Delayed::Job.delete_all
```

everything worked fine.

Comment: With workless 1.2.3 do you still need the initializer?  I thought this was fixed in PR #64.  But, not sure...

Comment: Hey Hellion, yes you are right. Init is no longer needed. Prior to realizing it is bad data, I surmised wrongly that init is needed.